# Inconsistent formatting observed in using Xtext formatter

Tags: java, xtext

I have xtext grammar as below :

```
MyDSLModel:
    (dmodel=DModel)
;

DModel:
    {DModel}
    (importSection=ImportSection)?
    (
        (groups+=Group) |
        (variableDefinition+=VariableDefinition)
    )*
;

ImportSection:
    (importDeclarations+=Import)+
;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=[DModel | ImportID]
;

ImportID:
    ImportIdentifier(('.'|'/')ImportIdentifier)*
;

Group:
    'group' name=Identifier
;

VariableDefinition:
    'var' name=Identifier
;

ImportIdentifier:
    Identifier
    | 'dB'
    | 'm'
    | 'true' | 'false'
    | 'parallel' | 'sequential'
    | 'sites' | 'routing'
;

Identifier:
    PortIdentifier
    | 'mode'
    | 'options'
;

PortIdentifier:
    SINGLE_CHARACTER_ID |  ID

    | 'action'
    | 'config'
    | 'disabled'
    | 'enum'
    | 'extension'
    | 'group'
    | 'import'
    | 'mod'
    | 'set'
    | 'setup'
;

terminal ID:
    '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')+
;

terminal SINGLE_CHARACTER_ID:
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')
;
```

Now, I have a file written using this grammar, which is as below :

```
import specification/FunctionalTIM.spec
import specification/FunctionalLEV.spec
import specification/FunctionalWVT.spec
group GR1
group GR2
var v1
var v2
```

I am trying to format this code with following implementation

```
public class MyDSLFormatter extends AbstractDeclarativeFormatter {

    @Inject
    private MyDSLGrammarAccess grammarAccess;

    @Override
    protected void configureFormatting(FormattingConfig c) {

    ImportElements importAccess = grammarAccess.getImportAccess();
    c.setLinewrap().after(importAccess.getRule());

    GroupElements groupAccess = grammarAccess.getGroupAccess();
    c.setLinewrap().after(groupAccess.getRule());

    VariableDefinitionElements varDefAccess = grammarAccess
                .getVariableDefinitionAccess();
    c.setLinewrap().after(varDefAccess.getRule());

}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is, inconsistency in formatting, when `Import` elements are present in my file If my file has import statements in it, then the line wrap for `VariableDefinition` (after the rule) is not taking effect. So, `CTRL+SHIFT+F` gives file as

```
import specification/FunctionalTIM.spec
import specification/FunctionalLEV.spec
import specification/FunctionalWVT.spec
group GR1 group GR2 var v1 var v2
```

Note:
If I am having only `Group` elements and `VariableDefinition` elements, then proper line wraps are getting inserted.

So, can anyone help, why this inconsistent behavior is observed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a parsing problem, that's why formatter is not behaving like it should.
The problem is in your Import rule:

```
Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=[DModel]
;
```

**[DModel]** is a syntactic sugar for **[DModel | ID]** so your rule is parsing ID and *"specification/FunctionalTIM.spec"* is not an ID terminal.

Try something like:

```
Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=[DModel | ImportID]
;
```

where

```
ImportID:
    ID  (('/' | '.') ID )*
;
```

Comment: Yes, your suggested rule is correct. But my problem starts after formatting the ImportElements. If you see the formatted code above, it shows, line wraps are behaving improperly for Group and Variable elements, all those are on the same line, even after inserting line wraps after them

Comment: @ Fabien :- thanks for your suggestion , I have edited the grammar. But the issue is not resolved. If you have any other suggestions , then please let me know.

Comment: I have the same grammar and formatter than you and when i press Ctrl+Shift+F formatting is OK. Do you have anything else that could cause this problem?

Comment: Is your problem view empty?

Comment: Fabien, I have added Identifier rule to the question asked above itself. Actually, my grammar is very vast.Even Identifier rule has lots of elements in it. I have posted just a template here, which is causing an issue.

Comment: With the grammar you gave, i can't reproduce your problem, formatter is working. Have you checked problem view for the example dsl file?